# JAVA_HOME variable under OSX... what is it exactly?

Tags: java, ant, build-process, scons, sphinx4

I've been trying to build evaldictator on OSX.  Unfortunately I have little to no idea of what ant or scons actually do.

My main question is when I do something like

```
export JAVA_HOME='/lab/speech/java/jdk1.5.0_06'
```

what am I doing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are telling ANT to use `java` executable at `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java`. This allows you to have many versions of JAVA installed in your system and you can pick a specific version.